# What is the use of "Ends." to indicate the end of a document?

Tags: formatting, ending

I recall seeing the word "Ends." placed at the end of documents to indicate that, obviously, nothing else follows. Is this acceptable standard usage? It feels rather archaic (not that that's necessarily a bad thing), although it does serve a purpose. Are there any alternatives?

[An example](http://constitutionallyspeaking.co.za/chief-justice-statement-on-death-of-cabinet-minister/):

> [...] just and truly free South Africa will be remembered by many generations to come” said Chief Justice Mogoeng.
>
> Ends.
>
> Enquiries

Comment: I don't think I've seen this.  Do you remember where you saw it - ie. what form of writing it was?

Comment: Could this be the same as "FIN" that you sometimes used to see at the end of films?

Comment: Context would really help here - screenplays? Tech writing? Newspaper columns? Long-form graffiti? Even if it's a common convention, it's probably a convention only in a very specific context.

Comment: @Craig: "Fin" is just the French word for "End". So "Fin" in French -language movies is the same as "The End" in old English-language movies.

Comment: @Roy Yes, I knew what it meant, but I've seen it in English films, too.

Comment: I'm trying to remember where I saw the word used. It may have been at the end of Minutes of a meeting or a report of some kind. I think I recall it being a (somewhat) formal piece, but certainly not a legal document.

Comment: Updated question with an example of usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is part of the standard way of finishing a press release. Some of these formal documents still use these conventions.

It comes, I think, from the time when press releases came on a teleprinter, and it was important to mark the end, so that it was clear to the recipient that the entire release had been received.

Answer (score 6):

I've seen two or three hash marks ## or -30- at the end of press releases and news articles.

Comment: "-30-"? Intriguing. What's that for?

Comment: @Standback - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E2%80%9330%E2%80%93

Comment: and the three Xs became three hash marks, as above.

Answer (score 4):

It's usually a full square that ends fx a news article. I believe there exist different kinds of text ending marks for different writing cultures, styles and genres. Take a look at these:

http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080903084042AAakPtI

http://desktoppub.about.com/cs/intermediate/a/endsigns.htm

http://desktoppub.about.com/od/glossary/g/End_Sign.htm

Comment: oh, a printer's dingbat. I never thought of that, but you're right. It does indicate the end of a piece, or an article within a larger publication.

Comment: And used in many ways - also in fx mathematic proofs or ending scientific examples.

Answer (score 0):

`###` and `--30--` are/were used as industry-specific conventions to standardize and add quality controls to copy.

fin and various ornamental dingbats are used on the finished product, for the viewers help in recognizing the end of an article, book, section, chapter, film, etc. Again, certain conventions are established for each industry, and of course these evolve with time.